# closing nested streams

Tags: java, inputstream, printwriter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best way to close nested streams in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/884007/best-way-to-close-nested-streams-in-java)

How we close nested streams? Closing all of them? If yes what is the order?

```
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("data.txt", true);
PrintWriter pout = new PrintWriter(out);

/* do some I/O */

pout.close();
out.close();
```

or closing the the out most stream will close all of them.

```
pout.close(); // Is this enough?
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When closing chained streams, you only need to close the outermost stream. Any errors will be propagated up the chain and be caught.

Take a look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/884007/best-way-to-close-nested-streams-in-java). Probably this question has been asked before.

Answer (score 3):

Always close resources with a `finally` block:

```
acquire();
try {
    use();
} finally {
    release();
}
```

Your only resource here is the `FileOutputStream`, so it's the only one which really needs to be closed. If the `PrintWriter` constructor was to throw, you really should release the `FileOutputStream` anyway, which precludes just closing the `PrintWriter`.

Note, you really do want to **`flush`**  the `PrintWriter`. This only needs to be done in the non-exception case so doesn't need a finally.