# How many of these wrapped Java I/O objects do I have to close?

Tags: java, stream

I want to write base64-encoded data to a file, decoding on the fly.  I have

```
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(
  new OutputStreamWriter(
    new Base64OutputStream(
      new FileOutputStream(myFile, false)));
```

I think this works, and in my `finally` block I call `bw.close()` -- that is, [close the outermost wrapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16363642/java-6-io-wrapped-streams-closing).  Is that enough, or are some of the anonymous intermediary objects going to leak?

I tried looking through the code but I got stuck at Sun's proprietary implementation of OutputStreamWriter's encoding-handlers.  It also doesn't appear to be spelled out explicitly in the documentation.

Comment: Dup of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6586866/closing-nested-streams and of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8080649/do-i-have-to-close-fileoutputstream-which-is-wrapped-by-printstream

Comment: I don't know why I couldn't find those.  Thanks @sara!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In general closing the outermost wrapper is enough; each wrapper closes the underlaying stream when it's closed.

It is possible to create a wrapper that doesn't do this, but that could be considered a bug since the documentation for `FilterOutputStream` requires that a call to close ["releases any system resources associated with the stream."](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FilterOutputStream.html#close%28%29)

Comment: The only class in JDK which I know to break this rule is `ZipOutputStream` which requires separate entry closing before calling `#close()`.

Answer (score 3):

The best approach is to close the outermost stream object.  Assuming that it is correctly implemented, this will call `close()` on the object that wraps, and the closes will propagate up the chain ... doing the right thing.

In the case of an output pipeline, it is actually *important* that you do it this way.  If you only close the innermost outputstream / writer, there is a chance that buffered output (somewhere in the pipeline) won't be written properly.

Answer (score 2):

Since [BufferedWriter extends AutoClosable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html), you can use [try-with-resources statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) in Java 7 to automatically close the resources when they are out of scope.

```
try(BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(
  new OutputStreamWriter(
    new Base64OutputStream(
      new FileOutputStream(myFile, false)));
   ) {

      // bw.write(); 

} catch(XXXException ex) {
    // Catch Block.
}
```

> The try-with-resources statement ensures that each resource is closed at the end of the statement

Also, the code looks cleaner this way.

Comment: I have to support Java 6, at least for the foreseeable future.  I'd definitely rather do this, though.