# What order should I follow to close the bufferedwriter and filewriter?

Tags: java

I know that BufferedWriter.close would automatically close the underlying filewriter source. But for some reason I have been given the task which requires closing both. So far I have been doing it in this order,

filewriter.close();

bufferwriter.close();

This order to me feels correct. The other way however,

bufferedwriter.close();

filewriter.close();

here, wont it throw a null pointer since the filewriter would already be closed? What is the correct order ? Also does the same apply to bufferedreader and filereader ?

Comment: This is not a duplicate I am asking only because I did go through the existing solutions and couldnt find a satisfactory response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
bufferedwriter.close();

filewriter.close();
```

This will not throw a null pointer exception. You may be thinking it would because the `close()` method of `BufferedWriter` sets the `Writer` field to `null`, but because Java passes object references by value, the original `FileWriter` is still not `null`. Closing it won't have any effect.

This is the implementation of `BufferedWriter#close()`:

```
public void close() throws IOException {
    synchronized (lock) {
        if (out == null) {
            return;
        }
        try {
            flushBuffer();
        } finally {
            out.close();  // this closes the FileWriter
            out = null;   // the original FileWriter passed to the BufferedWriter is still not null after this call
            cb = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And the same applies for bufferedreader and filereader as well, i assume ?

Comment: Also just out of curiosity, what would happen if I close filewriter.close() and then bufferdwriter.close(); wouldnt it have the same effect ?

Comment: @happyHelper Same for `BufferedReader`. And for the ordering difference, I suggest you check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6586866/closing-nested-streams and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/884007/best-way-to-close-nested-streams-in-java-6.

Answer (score 3):

From the `OutputStreamWriter.close()` documentation that `FileWriter` inherits.

> Closes the stream, flushing it first. Once the stream has been closed, further write() or flush() invocations will cause an IOException to be thrown. Closing a previously closed stream has no effect.

So you should be fine closing a `FileWriter` that was already closed by the `BufferedWriter`.

More information: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/OutputStreamWriter.html