# JAVA: IO Exception: Reason Stream closed

Tags: java, file, io, filewriter, bufferedwriter

Why am I getting the following exception? What I am doing is writing a giant ArrayList line by line to a file onto the disk. The file generated is about >700MB.
It seems like it has some problem when written line by line. Could the size of the file a reason? Why is the stream closed? By the way, I am working on a Windows OS.

```
FileWriter evaluated_result = 
    new FileWriter(path_output+this.algorithm+"/"+query_type+"/"+"queries.eval");
BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(evaluated_result);
out.write(Myobject);
out.newLine();
evaluated_result.close();
out.close();
```

The exception is as follows:

```
java.io.IOException: Stream closed
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.ensureOpen(StreamEncoder.java:45)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.write(StreamEncoder.java:118)
    at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.write(OutputStreamWriter.java:207)
    at java.io.BufferedWriter.flushBuffer(BufferedWriter.java:129)
    at java.io.BufferedWriter.close(BufferedWriter.java:264)
    at Assignment_1.Query_Evaluator.write100BestDocumentsEvalFormat(Query_Evaluator.java:85)
    at Assignment_1.Experiment.ConductExperiment(Experiment.java:54)
    at Assignment_1.Main.main(Main.java:78)
```

Answer (score 7):

You should close the `BufferedWriter` *before* closing the `FileWriter`.

And, the closing calls should be in a finally block. This is one way to do it (with one finally):

```
FileWriter evaluated_result = new FileWriter(path_output+this.algorithm+"/"+query_type+"/"+"queries.eval");
BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(evaluated_result);
try {
  out.write(Myobject);
  out.newLine();
}
finally {
  if (out != null) out.close();
  if (evaluated_result != null) evaluated_result.close();
}
```

(Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/884007/best-way-to-close-nested-streams-in-java) for more options)

Also note that, as mentioned by @oldrinb, you don't have to close nested streams. But I think it's good practice anyway.

With Java 7 you can use the [try-with-resources](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) statement.

Comment: Do you think closing BufferedWriter before closing FileWriter fix my problem? How can I define finally in try-catch-finally construct?

Comment: @Bob: I hope so. Please try it and report on the results :-)

Comment: You don't have to close the `FileWriter` at all.

Comment: @oldrinb: Thanks, I added a note about that.