# Is my usage of nested try-with-resource correct?

Tags: java

I have simple TCP server which prints the message sent by client. I'm trying to modify it to use try-with-resource feature. Is using nested try-with-resource statement in my example correct?

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
    String receivedMessage;

    try (ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(777)) {
        while (true) {
            Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
            System.out.println("Client connected");
            try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()))) {
                while ((receivedMessage = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(receivedMessage);
                }
                System.out.println("Client disconnected");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What makes you think it's not?

Comment: Googling made me think of it. Some users suggested to place two statements separated by semicolon in try clause. In my case it's not working. I'm just wondering if it is a good practice to use nested try-with-resource clauses, or some other effective solution exist.

Comment: you can't put both in one try block, because `socket.getInputStream()` in your second try block depends on `Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();` which happens inside the first try block

Comment: I updated my answer with an example of where your code could appropriately use multiple resources in try clause.

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12552863/correct-idiom-for-managing-multiple-chained-resources-in-try-with-resources-bloc) for some advice with respect to your chained resources in `try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream())))`

Answer (score 4):

Yes, your example is correct.

A try-with-resources `try` block can stand alone because it has an implicit `finally` block; whereas a traditional `try` block is required to be followed by a `catch` block and/or a `finally` block.

Thus your example code is equivalent to the following (besides the resource variables being visible outside the scope of their respective try blocks):

```
        final ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(777);
        try {
            while (true) {
                Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
                System.out.println("Client connected");
                final BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        socket.getInputStream()));
                try {
                    while ((receivedMessage = in.readLine()) != null) {
                        System.out.println(receivedMessage);
                    }
                    System.out.println("Client disconnected");
                } finally {
                    in.close();
                }
            }
        } finally {
            serverSocket.close();
        }
```

I would have recommended you put both resources inside the same try block, except in your case that doesn't work because it's necessary to call `accept()` on the serverSocket before asking for its `inputStream()`.

However, there's still an appropriate opportunity in your code example to put multiple resources in your second try-with-resources:

```
try (Reader stream = new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream());
     BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(stream)) {
  // do stuff, still preferring to use 'in' here rather than 'stream'
}
```

Comment: `serverSocket = new ServerSocket(777);` should go inside the try clause, io exceptions can also happen when opening them, same goes for the reader code.

Comment: @ThomasJungblut a lot of developers seem to have that misconception, which is unfortunate and results in a lot of unclean code: did the resource variable get initialized or not? They way I wrote it, there is no question. And since exceptions are not being caught in the example code, the enclosing method throws IOException regardless.

Comment: I don't want to start a flame war on a 6yo answer, but your code is problematic when people copy&paste it without thinking and catching the errors appropriately due to leaking sockets. And it is not exactly the same as the OP's actually correct code which guarantees that the socket created is properly closed. When your `ServerSocket` constructor throws an exception it's left dangling.

Comment: @ThomasJungblut sorry but you're just wrong... if the constructor throws an exception, the serverSocket variable is never assigned, hence there is nothing to clean up