# Why am I getting NullPointerException? bufferWriter.close()

Tags: java, android

I am new to this, but I am writing an app and I keep getting this error cause the app to crash on start.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void java.io.BufferedWriter.close()' on a null object reference
```

The code causing it is in the class below, there will be a HERE comment next to the line with the issue.

```
public class FileOptions extends Activity{

public void createFile(String title, String storeValue){
    BufferedWriter bufferWriter = null;
    try {
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = openFileOutput(title, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        bufferWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(fileOutputStream));

        String content = storeValue;

        bufferWriter.write(content);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {  //Cannot be removed
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        try {
       /**HERE*/ bufferWriter.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
//More unimportant stuff
}
```

This is the code where I am calling the method from.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
Context context = this;
boolean debug = true;
FileOptions file = new FileOptions();
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Boolean isFirstRun = getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE", MODE_PRIVATE)
            .getBoolean("isfirstrun", true);

    if(isFirstRun) {
        file.createFile("userInfo", "");
        getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE", MODE_PRIVATE).edit()
                .putBoolean("isfirstrun", false).commit();
    }

    if(file.readFile("userInfo") != "")
    {
        if(debug){alerter(file.readFile("userInfo"));alerter("true");}
        switchToHome();
    }else{
        if(debug){alerter("false");}
    }
}
}
```

Here is the stack trace.

```
08-27 22:44:35.830  13089-13089/? I/libpersona﹕ KNOX_SDCARD checking this for 10247

08-27 22:44:35.830  13089-13089/? I/libpersona﹕ KNOX_SDCARD not a persona

08-27 22:44:35.830  13089-13089/? E/Zygote﹕ MountEmulatedStorage()

08-27 22:44:35.830  13089-13089/? E/Zygote﹕ v2

08-27 22:44:35.830  13089-13089/? I/SELinux﹕ Function: selinux_compare_spd_ram, SPD-policy is existed. and_ver=SEPF_SM-N910V_5.0.1 ver=27

08-27 22:44:35.830  13089-13089/? I/SELinux﹕ Function: selinux_compare_spd_ram , priority [1] , priority version is VE=SEPF_SM-N910V_5.0.1_0027

08-27 22:44:35.830  13089-13089/? E/SELinux﹕ [DEBUG] get_category: variable seinfo: default sensitivity: NULL, cateogry: NULL

08-27 22:44:35.830  13089-13089/? I/art﹕ Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni

08-27 22:44:35.870  13089-13089/? D/TimaKeyStoreProvider﹕ TimaSignature is unavailable

08-27 22:44:35.870  13089-13089/? D/ActivityThread﹕ Added TimaKeyStore provider

08-27 22:44:35.920  13089-13089/? D/ResourcesManager﹕ creating new AssetManager 
and set to /data/app/preventioninnovations.preventapp-2/base.apk

08-27 22:44:36.050  13089-13089/? D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM

08-27 22:44:36.050  13089-13089/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: preventioninnovations.preventapp, PID: 13089
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{preventioninnovations.preventapp/preventioninnovations.preventapp.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void java.io.BufferedWriter.close()' on a null object reference
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2712)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2777)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:179)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1462)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5972)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void java.io.BufferedWriter.close()' on a null object reference
            at preventioninnovations.preventapp.FileOptions.createFile(FileOptions.java:37)
            at preventioninnovations.preventapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:38)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6289)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2777)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:179)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1462)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5972)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: It would be helpful seeing your stacktrace

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: before calling bufferWriter.close() check whether it is not null. if it is null, you can not call .close() which returns NPE.

Comment: It may be similar but I feel that with the differences in the code it is OK to ask a new question.

Comment: Well the same code works if I don't separate it out into a class, so I guess that is what I am going with. I realize that you can check if it is null but then it will not create the file needed(I think?)

Answer (score 5):

This happens when your `openFileOutput()` method throws an exception.

Since an exception was thrown `bufferWriter` was not initialized to a valid object.

And the exception caused the execution to skip the rest of try block go to catch block and then finally block.

So, when it reached the finally block, `bufferWriter` was `null`.

```
finally {
        try {
            if (bufferWriter != null)
                bufferWriter.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

To fix, check for `null` before calling close in `bufferWriter`.

Or still better use **try with resources**.

```
try(BufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(
                         new OutputStreamWriter(
                             openFileOutput(title, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)))) {}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
finally {
    if(bufferWriter!=null){
        bufferWriter.close();/**HERE*/
    }
}
```

By the looks your bufferWriter is null. So maybe the file you are giving it is not working? This stop a NPE if bufferwriter is null.

Answer (score 1):

**Java 7 gives you a much cleaner interface for try-catch blocks.**

You can read more on the alternative methods [from this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12665271/67945).

```
public void createFile(String title, String storeValue){
    try (
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = openFileOutput(title, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        BufferedWriter bufferWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(fileOutputStream))
    ) {
        String content = storeValue;
        bufferWriter.write(content);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue. I needed to pass the context of the class I was calling from to the method for it to work.

I had:`file.createFile("userInfo", "");` and I needed:`file.createFile("userInfo", "", this);`

then in the method I had:

```
public void createFile(String title, String storeValue){
    BufferedWriter bufferWriter = null;
    try {
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = openFileOutput(title, context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        bufferWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(fileOutputStream));
```

Where I needed:

```
public void createFile(String title, String storeValue, /** ADDED */Context context){
    BufferedWriter bufferWriter = null;
    try {
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = /** CHANGE IS HERE */ context.openFileOutput(title, context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        bufferWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(fileOutputStream));
```