# Are the resources without reference automatically closed too while using try-with-resources

Tags: java, try-with-resources

Example:

```
try(ResultSet rs = DriverManager.getConnection(url, us, pw).createStatement().executeQuery(sql)) {

    //mycode
}
```

I don't have any reference to `Connection` or `Statement`, will they be closed too and if they do what is the order?

thanks

Comment: See this question for a discussion on the topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12552863/correct-idiom-for-managing-multiple-chained-resources-in-try-with-resources-bloc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [language specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.3), it will only close the `ResultSet` object. This is because the try-with-resources statement makes use of a resource specification where a resource is declared using a variable:

> *`TryWithResourcesStatement:`*
>
> > *`try ResourceSpecification Block [Catches] [Finally]`*
>
> *`ResourceSpecification:`*
>
> > *`( ResourceList [;] )`*
>
> *`ResourceList:`*
>
> > *`Resource {; Resource}`*
>
> **`Resource:`**
>
> > **`{VariableModifier} UnannType VariableDeclaratorId = Expression`**

Comment: is this correct:
the resources in my code will be closed Automatically by closing the only available reference which is ResultSet rs, similar to the fact that resources which were Wrapped by other resources like:
new OutputStream(new FileOutputStream()) 
FileOutputStream will be closed Automatically by closing OutputStream

Comment: @Seyjowzeetaapoogiukaagee No it's not correct. Closing `ResultSet` does not close a `Statement` nor the `Connection`.

Comment: what about nested streams? will the wrapped streams be closed if try-with-resource statement close the outermost stream

Comment: Yes usually the wrapped streams are closed automatically.