# Java try-with-resource when one resource wraps another

Tags: java, try-with-resources

Lets say I need to have this instance `new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(path)))`, what is the best way to write this using try with resource.

*1. What I am used to write - because only the first Closable need to be closed*

```
try (FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(path)) {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fileInputStream));
    ...
}
```

*2. The outer most Closable closes its inner Closable etc.*

```
try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(path)))) {
    ...
}
```

*3. Use a separate resource for each Closable*

```
try (
        FileInputStream fileInputSream = new FileInputStream(path);
        InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(fileInputSream);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(fileInputSream)) {
    ...
}
```

Thanks,

Ido Sorozon

Comment: Your type of question appears to have been asked [many times previously on this site](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+try+with+resources+multiple+resources+site:stackoverflow.com)

Comment: It is a different question, I've searched the web and the only answer I could find was when I have 2 separate resources. however one of your search results [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12552863/correct-idiom-for-managing-multiple-chained-resources-in-try-with-resources-bloc) touch my dilemma, maybe my search string was not good enough

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a more readable option (extract method):

```
try (BufferedReader reader = getBufferReader()) {
```