# How to close a file in java

Tags: java

This is my code :

```
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(log,true);
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(sw);

fw.close();
bw.close();
sw.close();
pw.close();
```

I want to change it to something like this :

```
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(log,true));
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new StringWriter());

bw.close();
pw.close();
```

Will this be correct, or will the missing `close()` calls cause problems?

Comment: From the documentation if `PrintWriter#close`: `Closes the stream and releases any system resources associated with it. Closing a previously closed stream has no effect.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be sure the close is not forgotten you could use the `try-with-resource` statement

```
try (BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(log, true));
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new StringWriter())) {
    // do your processing here
} catch (IOException ex) {
    // do your exception handling
}
```

The compiler will add for your the appropriate code for the `close()`.

Comment: This is also safer in the case of exceptions being launched, since the streams will be closed regardless of exceptions --- which is not the case in any of the 2 proposed variants in the OP

Answer (score 0):

When you close a *BufferedWriter* Object which takes a *FileWriter* Object in its constructor, then implicitly the *FileWriter* Object is also closed.

So to answer your question, both ways are fine and the same and it *don't make any problem*

[Previous Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16584777/is-it-necessary-to-close-a-filewriter-provided-it-is-written-through-a-buffered)

[Best practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/884007/best-way-to-close-nested-streams-in-java-6)

Answer (score 0):

Since Java 7 you can let java automatically close the resources for you. Take a look at the [try with resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html).

```
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path))) {
    return br.readLine();
}
```