# Cannot run program through a Process after downloading it (Java)

Tags: java, download, cmd, java-io

After downloading a program (NirCmd) like so:

```
        URL website = new URL(
                "https://copy.com/Q4qch6FBPZkrclxG/nircmd.exe?download=1");
        ReadableByteChannel rbc = Channels.newChannel(website.openStream());
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("nircmd.exe");

        fos.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc, 0, Long.MAX_VALUE);
```

And then running it like so:

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("nircmd.exe speak text Hi");
```

But it throws this exception:

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "nircmd.exe": CreateProcess error=32, The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
at Main.main(Main.java:18)

Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=32, The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process
at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(Unknown Source)
... 5 more
```

Answer (score 4):

Close the OutputStream. Otherwise (at least in Windows) it maintains an exclusive write-lock on the underlying file resource for some undetermined duration.

Streams *should* be handled by calling [`close`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Closeable.html) in a deterministic manner to avoid this very problem.

If `close` is *not* called then the stream will "be closed at some undetermined time in the future when/if the finalizer runs or the program exits". As seen, this non-deterministic behavior can lead to bugs and erratic behavior.

To make life easier, because it is very tedious to correctly wrap and call `close` methods, a [*try*-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) statement can be used:

```
try (
  ReadableByteChannel rbc = Channels.newChannel(website.openStream());
  FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("nircmd.exe"))
) {
    fos.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc, 0, Long.MAX_VALUE);
}

// Now nircmd.exe can be opened because fos.close()
// is GUARANTEED to have been called (by try-with-resources)
// and the underlying file is no longer [exclusively] opened.
```

While it isn't as important (in this case) to close the read channel it should be done for the sake of hubris, consistency, and practice.

---

Addendum:

Adding in a random `File.exists` check does not actually 'fix' the problem - *although it may trigger a side-effect that makes it "appear to work" it is unreliable code.*

The file *does* exist or the exception which reads "[the file that does exist] is being used by another process" would be different. The problem is that the file is still *opened* by the current process in a non-shared mode.

---

[Is it necessary to close each nested OutputStream and Writer separately?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28276423/is-it-necessary-to-close-each-nested-outputstream-separately) is a fairly good at-a-glance-read and should be a good jumping off point to related questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use java lib "Apache Commons IO" to done it.

My Simple Code:

```
URL url = new URL("https://copy.com/Q4qch6FBPZkrclxG/nircmd.exe?download=1");
InputStream input = url.openStream();
String exef= "nircmd.exe";
FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(exef);
IOUtils.copy(input, output);
```

Class "IOUtils" is a common tool for IO stream operation in commons-io jar.

Comment: While IOUtils can be handy, this has the same problem as the original: the file (as created/written via FileOutputStream) is not closed in a deterministic manner. The [`IOUtils.copy`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#copy(java.io.InputStream,%20java.io.OutputStream)) method does not close the streams automatically: "*Wherever possible, the methods in this class do not flush or close the stream .. Thus **the caller is still responsible for closing streams after use**.*" Valid solutions involve some form of deterministic `close`.

Answer (score -2):

Fixed! Here's how I did it:

When it ran:

```
    URL website = new URL(
            "https://copy.com/Q4qch6FBPZkrclxG/nircmd.exe?download=1");
    ReadableByteChannel rbc = Channels.newChannel(website.openStream());
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("nircmd.exe");

    fos.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc, 0, Long.MAX_VALUE);
```

It needed a:

```
if(new File("nircmd.exe").exists())  {
    ... code here
}
```

Comment: This doesn't fix the problem. It only hides it.