# How to write data in locked file?

Tags: java

I want to write an XML data inside my  locked file I have a logic like this, but my file data isn't replaced by this text data and i   got  exception  like

> this:Exception in thread "main"
>   java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException  at
>   sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.ensureOpen(FileChannelImpl.java:110)   at
>   sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.write(FileChannelImpl.java:199)    at
>   sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.writeBytes(StreamEncoder.java:218)   at
>   sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implClose(StreamEncoder.java:316)    at
>   sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.close(StreamEncoder.java:149)    at
>   java.io.BufferedWriter.close(BufferedWriter.java:266)     at
>   java_io_Closeable$close.call(Unknown Source)  at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:117)
>     at locckGroovy.main(loccky.groovy:90)

. What should I change to make this?

```
 RandomAccessFile ini = new RandomAccessFile(file, "rwd");
        FileLock lock = ini.getChannel().tryLock();
    try{

        w=new BufferedWriter(Channels.newWriter(ini.getChannel(),"UTF-8"));
        w.write(text);

    }finally{

    ini.close();

    }
```

Comment: Are you calling `w.close()` at the end?

Comment: yes   i  do .....,,,,,,,

Comment: Updated code example doesn't compile (`ini` is declared in `try` block and is  not accessible in `finally`)

Comment: even if i   export  ini  out  of  try and have  only   ini.close() inside finally it  doesn't  update  file

Comment: You still need to call `w.close` and you need to do it before `ini.close`

Comment: is it  lnormal   to  have  only  ini.close() in  finallly  code  i mean  if   file  channel  will be  closed  BufferedWriter  and  related  stream  will  close  itself  or  i am mistaken?

Comment: Nope, `BufferedWriter.close` will probably close an underlying channel, but it surely won't work the other way around.

Comment: Do  you  mean  that BufferedWriter.close will lose ini  ?

Comment: I would expect it to happen, but [there are exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28276423/is-it-necessary-to-close-each-nested-outputstream-and-writer-separately). Since java 7, you can use try-with-resources for both `w` and `ini`, this way you don't need to call `close` explicitly. Check out the answers in the linked question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you have to close streams in the opposite order of creating/opening them.

It seems that `w` is being closed after `ini`. When trying to close `w`, it attempts to close the underlying stream `ini`, which has already been closed.

Move `w.close()` before `ini.close()`, or move `ini.close()` after `w.close()`.

Comment: By  the  way  do   you  know  if  it  is   enough  to write w.rite(" ")   for making  related  file empty in  this  code?  w=new BufferedWriter(Channels.newWriter(ini.getChannel(),"UTF-8"));
            w.write("");
            w.write(text);

Comment: To make an empty file, you don't need any `write()`s. Just opening and closing it should do it as well. `write("")` actually doesn't do anything.

Comment: i  mean  when  i  write something in  this  file  it  has  already  have  content i need  to replace  this  data   with mine

Comment: In other  words  i need  my  newly  updated data  to be  not appended  but  replaced

Comment: You are using a `RandomAccessFile` here, I think you can use `setLength(0)` to truncate it. But do you really need a `RandomAccessFile`? If all you need is to write out a file, I suggest you use a vanilla `FileOutputStream` + `BufferedOutputStream`. It will create a new file every time. Also note you are using synchronous writes here (`"rwd"`), which might be slow.