# Do I need to keep variables for all writers/readers to close them all manually?

Tags: java, file-io, filereader, filewriter

Consider this example:

```java
public class FileAppender implements AutoCloseable {
    private final FileWriter fileWriter;
    private final BufferedWriter bufferedWriter;

    public FileAppender(String fileName) throws IOException {
        fileWriter = new FileWriter(fileName, true)
        bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);
    }

    public void appendLine(String line) throws IOException {
        bufferedWriter.write(line + "\n");
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws Exception {
        bufferedWriter.close();
        fileWriter.close();
    }
}
```

Here we keep an unused `FileWriter` as a member of the class, just so we can manually close it later. There are many tutorials in the web which show examples like this where multiple streams are closed manually.

We could instead implement the same class more concisely:

```java
public class FileAppender implements AutoCloseable {
    private final BufferedWriter writer;

    public FileAppender(String fileName) throws IOException {
        writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(fileName, true));
    }

    public void appendLine(String line) throws IOException {
        writer.write(line + "\n");
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws Exception {
        writer.close();
    }
}
```

Same applies to the usage of `FileReader` and `BufferedReader`.

Would there be any difference between the above two implementations?

Comment: Closely related: [*Is it necessary to close each nested OutputStream and Writer separately?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28276423/is-it-necessary-to-close-each-nested-outputstream-and-writer-separately), but there the streams/writers are being used within a method so answers there primarily focus on suggesting try-with-resources, which obviously you can't use. The first paragraph of [my answer there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28276498/157247) applies, but...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `BufferedWriter`, specifically, you can just use `close` on the `BufferedWriter` and it will call `close` on the underlying `FileWriter`.

**But**, as far as I'm aware, that's not documented, and not required of `Writer` implementations that wrap other `Writer`s (and similarly, streams). I'm paranoid, and tend to close things explicitly (in reverse order of opening them).

You can see the close operation in the `BufferedWriter` source (this example is from JDK 11.0.1), though you have to look fairly closely:

```
public void close() throws IOException {
    synchronized (lock) {
        if (out == null) {
            return;
        }
        try (Writer w = out) {
            flushBuffer();
        } finally {
            out = null;
            cb = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Note the use of try-with-resources to auto-close `out` (via `w`).