Try-with-resources - Whether object inside another object which is auto cloable gets closed?
See the below code snippet:
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;

public class FileReadWriteTest {

  public static void main(String args[]) {

    String data = "This is the data in the output file2";
    String filepPath = "D:\\TVC\\customer_issues\\TVCO-421\\test.txt";
    
    try ( BufferedWriter output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(filepPath)) ) {

      // Writes the string to the file
      output.write(data);

    }
    catch (Exception e) {
      e.getStackTrace();
    } finally {
        
    }
  } 
}

Here the FileWriter is created inside the BufferedWriter in try-with-resources. So, I knew that BufferedWriter gets auto closed. But what about FileWriter ? Wil it also gets auto-closed how to verify that ????

Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28276423/is-it-necessary-to-close-each-nested-outputstream-and-writer-separately
