# How to correctly close nested ZipInputStreams?

Tags: java, try-with-resources, zipinputstream

I am reading a nested zip file (a zip file containing multiple other zip files) **in memory** with the following code

```
try (ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(inputStream)) {
   ZipEntry zipEntry;
   while ((zipEntry = zis.getNextEntry()) != null) {
      if (zipEntry.getName().endsWith(".zip")) {
         ZipInputStream nestedZis = new ZipInputStream(zis);
         Pojo myPojo = myPojoReader.readFrom(nestedZis);
      }
   }
   zis.closeEntry();
}
```

The code works fine, but I get StrictMode violation errors (in Android) since the nested Stream `nestedZis` is not closed properly.

The problems:

1. I cannot instantiate it earlier since I have to call `zis.getNextEntry()` before in order to position the outer stream correctly
2. I cannot close it within the while loop since that would also close the outer ZipInputStream

Is there a solution that handles the resources correctly?

**Note** I am explicitly not asking about chained streams as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/884007/correct-way-to-close-nested-streams-and-writers-in-java). I cannot include the nested stream in the try-with-resources statement because of the first problem mentioned above.

**Note** I can not use `ZipFile` since I can only get an Inputstream as my initial resource and do not have access to the File.

Comment: You need to put `zip.closeEntry()` inside the while loop.

Comment: That does not change anything, since `getNextEntry()` calls `closeEntry()`internally.

Comment: You're right. Does Apache's CloseShieldInputStream help?

Comment: It does! Thank you for the hint. Do you want to add this as an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: I'm glad my idea has helped, but I'm not familiar with StrictMode so I'll leave it to someone (possibly yourself) to write a good answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the tip from @k314159 to use Apache's [`CloseShieldInputStream`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/input/CloseShieldInputStream.html) which is part of Apache Commons IO library I changed my code to:

```
try (ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(inputStream)) {
   ZipEntry zipEntry;
   while ((zipEntry = zis.getNextEntry()) != null) {
      if (zipEntry.getName().endsWith(".zip")) {
         try (CloseShieldInputStream cloned = CloseShieldInputStream.wrap(zis); ZipInputStream nestedZis = new ZipInputStream(cloned)) {
            Pojo myPojo = myPojoReader.readFrom(nestedZis);
         }
      }
   }
   zis.closeEntry();
}
```

This preserves the functionality of my code while also passing Android's StrictMode verifications.

The `CloseShieldInputStream` is a proxy stream that prevents the underlying input stream from being closed.

**Note** There also is a `CloseShieldOutputStream` which I now use for the generating of the nested zip.